# How to resize Tab name area in Pyviz Panel

Tags: python, tabs, pyviz, holoviz, panel-pyviz

I'm trying to create a tab layout using Pyviz-Panel (example code below) in a Jupyter notebook. I'd like to keep the size of individual tab *name*s the same.
However, `tab.width` changes/sets the size of the overall window for the Tabs set.

Even `tab[0].width` sets window width for the contents within tab 'A' i.e., the width of the column/button in my example below. That's not what I'm after.

How do I change the width of the *name area* for each tab?

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
import panel.widgets as pnw

name_list = ['A','BBB','CCCCC']
tab_contents = name_list
buttons = [pnw.Button(name="Do "+name) for name in tab_contents]
columns = [pn.layout.Column() for i in range(len(name_list))]

tab = pn.layout.Tabs()
for i in range(len(name_list)):
    columns[i].extend([buttons[i]])
    tab.append((name_list[i],columns[i]))

tab
```

Comment: Great question, to which I unfortunately don't know the answer as my expertise is more on HoloViews. It's best to post your question here I think: https://discourse.holoviz.org/

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that such a forum existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
raw_css = """
.bk-root .bk-tabs-header.bk-above .bk-headers, .bk-root .bk-tabs-header.bk-below .bk-headers{
font-size:20px;
}
"""

pn.extension(raw_css=[raw_css])
```

You can adjust the font-size to get the desired size of the name area of tabs.

**Caveat:**

`KaTeX` stops working if the above is used. Hence, use `mathjax` to render any equations.